# authentication principal do not extract. Spring boot 3

Tags: java, spring, oauth-2.0, single-sign-on

I am using sprong boot 3 for authentication via google, I want to extract user info, authentication do not save in memory any info. Please help.

My configuration looks like this

```
import lombok.RequiredArgsConstructor;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationProvider;
import org.springframework.security.config.Customizer;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.method.configuration.EnableMethodSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configurers.AbstractHttpConfigurer;
import org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextHolder;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.registration.ClientRegistration;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.registration.ClientRegistrationRepository;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.registration.InMemoryClientRegistrationRepository;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.web.OAuth2AuthorizationRequestRedirectFilter;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.core.AuthorizationGrantType;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.core.ClientAuthenticationMethod;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.core.oidc.IdTokenClaimNames;
import org.springframework.security.web.SecurityFilterChain;


@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@EnableMethodSecurity
public class SecurityConfiguration {

    private static final String[] WHITE_LIST_URL = {"/api/v1/auth/**",
            "/v2/api-docs",
            "/v3/api-docs",
            "/v3/api-docs/**",
            "/swagger-resources",
            "/swagger-resources/**",
            "/configuration/ui",
            "/configuration/security",
            "/swagger-ui/**",
            "/webjars/**",
            "/swagger-ui.html",
            "/hello", "/principal"};


    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .authorizeHttpRequests(authorize -> authorize.requestMatchers(WHITE_LIST_URL).permitAll()
                        .anyRequest().authenticated()
                ).oauth2Login(Customizer.withDefaults());
        return http.build();
    }

    @Bean
    public ClientRegistrationRepository clientRegistrationRepository() {
        return new InMemoryClientRegistrationRepository(this.googleClientRegistration());
    }
    private ClientRegistration googleClientRegistration() {
        return ClientRegistration.withRegistrationId("google")
                .clientId("590537783892-9pm6e7lk7808p0e257tsb3nvpf2r8b3p.apps.googleusercontent.com")
                .clientSecret("<secret>")
                .clientAuthenticationMethod(ClientAuthenticationMethod.CLIENT_SECRET_BASIC)
                .authorizationGrantType(AuthorizationGrantType.AUTHORIZATION_CODE)
                .redirectUri("http://localhost:8080/principal")
                .scope("openid", "email", "phone")
                .authorizationUri("https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth")
                .tokenUri("https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token")
                .userInfoUri("https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/userinfo")
                .userNameAttributeName(IdTokenClaimNames.SUB)
                .jwkSetUri("https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/certs")
                .clientName("google")
                .build();
    }

}
```

trying to exctract principal details

```
import org.springframework.security.core.Authentication;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
public class GooogleAuthentication {

    @GetMapping("/principal")
    public Object sayHello(Authentication authentication) {
        return authentication != null ? authentication : "no auth" ;
    }
}
```

I am using sprong boot 3 for authentication via google, I want to extract user info, authentication do not save in memory any info. Please help.